# Using scanf to read a string then a integer, reads string only

Tags: c, string, int, scanf

I'm trying to use two scanf's to read a string and then an integer. The program waits for me to enter the string, i press enter and then doesn't wait for me to insert the integer. The code i'm using:

```
printf("Insert the name of the author to search: ");
scanf("%300s", author);

printf("Insert the year: ");
scanf("%d", &year);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the input you are typing in for the first `scanf()`?

Comment: Note: Using `"300"` makes sense if code has `char author[301]`.  But if code has `char author[300]`, use `"299"` in the format.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The conversion specifier `"%s"` breaks on whitespace.

If you enter, for instance, "John Smith", the variable `author` will have `"John"` and the rest of the input will be used for `year`.

Always validate the return value of (most) library functions.

```
printf("Insert the name of the author to search: ");
if (scanf("%300s", author) != 1) /* error */;

printf("Insert the year: ");
if (scanf("%d", &year) != 1) /* error */;
```

The best way to get user input is to use `fgets()`, then, if needed, parse the input and assign to variables.

```
char tmp[1000];

printf("Insert the name of the author to search: ");
if (!fgets(tmp, sizeof tmp, stdin)) /* error */;
strcpy(author, tmp);

printf("Insert the year: ");
if (!fgets(tmp, sizeof tmp, stdin)) /* error */;
if (sscanf(tmp, "%d", &year) != 1) /* error */;
```

Comment: The "%300s" specifier seems to solve the issue of breaking on withespace.
I was trying to avoid fgets due to all the extra parsing nedded, isn't this possible to solve only with scanf at all?

Comment: @pmg What about the trailing newline, if its there ?

Comment: `scanf()` has a *scanset* specifier. You may want to try it: `if (scanf("%300[a-z A-Z0-9,.]", author) != 1) /* error */;`

Comment: newline is whitespace, The `scanf()` specifier `"%s"` ignores newlines.

Comment: `if (scanf(" %300[a-z A-Z0-9,.]"` would help consume leading white-space.

Answer (score 1):

you are trying to read input into `author` array where input length can be upto 300 characters,So i hope that you have declared your array size as`char author[301]` , 300+1 (one extra for accomadating '\0').

You can use function like this `scanf(" %300[^\n],author")` this means keep reading characters from keyboard(or  you can say keyboard buffer) until `'\n'` is found, and `'\n'` is generated when you hit Enter key,Hence we are forcing `scanf()` to read characters until we hit enter.

We can use `fgets()` but one of the problem of it is that it will even read `'\n'` into array,which will always print the output of next `printf() operation` on one extra new line.This can cause problem when you want your output to be in tabular form.

```
int main()
{
   char author[301]="\0";//initialize char array to '\0' NULL's
   int year;
   printf("Insert the name of the author to search: ");

   if( scanf(" %300[^\n]", author)!=1 )
   {
       printf("End of Input or Error Occurred reading Name.\n");
       return 1;// return (NON-ZERO) means unsuccessful termination
   }

   printf("Insert the year: ");
   if( scanf("%d", &year)!=1 )
   {
       printf("End of Input or Error Occurred reading Year.\n");
       return 1;// return (NON-ZERO) means unsuccessful termination
   }    
return 0;
}
```